# How to get help for S4 class in R?

Tags: r

Beginners in R know how to use `?` and `help` to learn about a topic. But how to get the documentation about S4 classes?

I could not find a systematic discussion of this. There are brief mentions of `method ?`, `methods ?`, `method ? generic("class")`.

Is this how to get help?

Comment: you can check this [link](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/S4.html)

Comment: I've read that link before but didn't find out how to get help. I might miss something. Could you point out the relevant part?

Comment: Usually you can find the documentation of a class using the `-class` suffix. For instance, in the package `sp`, try `?"SpatialPolygons-class"` to get the doc relative to `SpatialPolygons` objects.

Comment: @nicola Usually I want to get help for a method? For example, if I do `?predict`, it only shows the help for the methods of S3 class. How to get the help for `predict` of, let's say, `mle2`, a S4 class?

Comment: Are you talking about the `bbmle` package? You can try `?"predict-methods"`.

Comment: @nicola What if there are two functions of the same name for two S4 classes? How does `?"predict-methods"` know that I'm looking for `predict` of the `mle2` class?

Comment: If there is a conflict, the help page will give you the choice between the doc of different packages. Try for instance `require(dplyr);?filter`. The `filter` function exists in both `base` and `dplyr` packages. The help will give you the choice.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/102933/discussion-between-heisenberg-and-nicola).